# Why m I getting a segmentation error when my code gives correct output?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
    
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    map<string,int>m;
    string name;
    int choice, marks;
    while(n>0)
    {
        cin>>choice>>name;
        if(choice==1)
        {
            cin>>marks;
            map<string,int>::iterator itr=m.find(name);
            if(itr==m.end())
            {
              m.insert(make_pair(name,marks)); 
               
            }
            else{
                itr->second=itr->second+marks;
               
            }

        }
        
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            map<string,int>::iterator itr=m.find(name);
             itr->second=0;
        }
        
        else if(choice==3){
            map<string,int>::iterator itr=m.find(name);
            cout<<itr->second<<endl;
        }
        
        n--;
        
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

- Reading symbols from Solution...done.

[New LWP 144748]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./Solution'.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f4200000000 in ?? ()

To enable execution of this file add
add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

To completely disable this security protection add
set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "//.gdbinit".

For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"*

Comment: What input are you giving to your program that causes this crash?  Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Where is it crashing ? On what inputs?

Comment: When choice is 3 you have: `cout<<itr->second<<endl;` what happens if name was not found? You assume it is always found. Same problem when choice is 2.

Answer (score 0):

What is the input to your program?

A segmentation fault occurs when you access memory outside of your memory location.

I suspect choice 2 and choice 3 can cause segmentation fault anytime.
Because even though the input name is not present in the map, you are trying to change its value.
Its not safe.